# App engine URLError download error in dev_appserver.py. "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to download a large remote file, and am getting a new error.. I've never seen this before and the URL I am trying works when I put it into my browser.

I request the URL with:

```
    startDownloadTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    logging.info("Download Start Time: "+startDownloadTime.strftime("%H:%M.%S"))
    url = [MY URL]
    logging.info("Starting download")
    r = requests.get(url)
    logging.info("Download complete")
```

Here is the full trace:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
req.respond()
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 269, in __call__
return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 149, in __call__
self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 264, in _flush_logs
apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/username/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

It is a large file so I found myself having to use sockets in order to download it, so this app.yaml file has:

```
env_variables:
   GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'
```

In it. Any ideas?

**Edit**: Just wanted to add that this is specific for the local development server and works in my production code.

**Edit 2**: Just to add -- the script works for a few minutes before crashing out so it seems like it is trying to download a file..

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it -- I was running out of ports and increased the port range with:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="15000 61000"
```

and it started working.